# Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:8000/src/client/assets/data.json

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, angular-httpclient

HI I am new to angular I am trying to read the json array from a file and I am getting failed to parse error.Can some one please guide me.

I have folder structure like below

src

```
--assets
    ---app
      -----opportunities
            ------opportunities.component.ts
--data.json
```

and my data.json file data is as below

```
[  
    {
     "Account name": "155874744",
     "Oppty owner": "Sony Europe Ltd.",
     "Product/s": "June 10, 2015",
     "Domestic/Mow": "55434992111033",
     "ASAP solution status": "Aasd",
     "Price scenario status": "$253.00"         
    },
    {
     "Account name": "155874744",
     "Oppty owner": "Sony Europe Ltd.",
     "Product/s": "June 10, 2015",
     "Domestic/Mow": "55434992111033",
     "ASAP solution status": "sds",
     "Price scenario status": "$253.00"        
    }     
]
```

and code in opportunities.component.ts is like below

```
 constructor(private httpservice:HttpClient){}
  public  opptyData:any[];
    ngOnInit()
    {                 
      this.httpservice.get('src/client/assetsdata.json').subscribe(data=>{
                this.opptyData = data as string[];
                console.log(this.opptyData[1]);
            },
            (err:HttpErrorResponse)=>{
                console.log(err.message);
            }               
            );
    }
```

I am not understanding what is an issue?? Please some one help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

The url should be just

```
 this.httpservice.get('./data.json').subscribe(data=>{
     this.opptyData = data as string[];
     console.log(this.opptyData[1]);
}
```

Comment: still getting the same error:Is there any issue with my file format?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to create structure of front-end by using dummy json then i will recommend you to use this [website](https://www.mocky.io/)

just paste your `JSON` and select your options then click on `Generate my http response`. it will generate a service link which you can use in your code for time being.
otherwise you can try `Sajeetharan` method.

Gud luck

Answer (score 0):

Store data in assets folder:

where src/assets/data.json

Folder Structure:

```
src
   -assets
      -data.json
```

**access as below: // (assets/data.json)**

```
constructor(private httpservice:HttpClient){}
  public  opptyData:any[];
    ngOnInit()
    {

            this.httpservice.get('assets/data.json').subscribe(data=>{
                    this.opptyData = data as string[];
                    console.log(this.opptyData[1]);

            },
            (err:HttpErrorResponse)=>{
                console.log(err.message);
            }

            );

    }
```

OR -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Folder Structure:

```
src
   -assets
     -client
       -data.json
```

**access as below: // (assets/client/data.json)**

```
constructor(private httpservice:HttpClient){}
  public  opptyData:any[];
    ngOnInit()
    {

            this.httpservice.get('assets/client/data.json').subscribe(data=>{
                    this.opptyData = data as string[];
                    console.log(this.opptyData[1]);

            },
            (err:HttpErrorResponse)=>{
                console.log(err.message);
            }

            );

    }
```